# ascii decode error even though everything being unicode ( python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, dataflow

i am running a script in dataflow (apache beam) it runs in **python 2.7.12** and does some text processing with unicode strings.

Amongst the processing i do the following, where *noun* and *phrase* are unicode ( i think... )

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
key = u"{}_{}".format(
    noun, phrase.replace(u" ", u"_")
)
```

However it yields ascii decode errors

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can put in debugging and get a repr of the strings used in as *noun* and *phrase* but i currently don't have them since my logging didn't output them.

i don't understand the ascii decode error when i think i am pretty specific that i want everything in unicode!

can you give some hints or should i come back with more info about the input strings?

Comment: What are `noun` and `phrase`? It sounds like `phrase` has the character `0xe2`. In `latin1` this is an `â` which is not a true ascii character.

Comment: But does it matter when i am explicetly creating a unicode string @FHTMitchell

Comment: Yes -- python only automatically encodes ascii

Comment: How do you create noun and phrase?

Comment: `noun` or `phrase` or both are not Unicode strings.  `.decode()` them first with the correct codec.  Python 2 will try to automatically decode byte strings to Unicode strings, but will use `ascii` codec.  Python 3 will not automatically try, so you catch the error immediately, even if the string is ASCII-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a colleague reminded me that i could always just decode the whole output, in this case being the key, to whatever format i chose.

```
key = u"{}_{}_{}_{}".format(
     business_unit_id, date, noun, phrase.replace(u" ", u"_")
    ).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

in the case i wanted ascii output and not care about missing chars like .

i could also use `...).encode('utf-8')` if i wanted that output in unicode.

in my case i settled with ascii output as the pipeline in apache beam did not seem happy with unicode keys in its map reduce pipelines

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have a non ascii character in your string. You need to convert `phrase` into unicode directly

```
 phrase.decode('latin-1')
```

before manipulating in `unicode.format`